# Unable to remove Textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core

I have created checkbox using asp.net core as:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="EthinicalGroups" class="control-label"></label><br />
    @{int i = 0;}
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.EthinicalGroup)
    {
        <input name="EthinicalGroup" value="@item.Id" type="checkbox" id="EthinicalGroup[@i]" />
        <label>@item.Name</label><br />
        i++;
    }
</div>
```

On check in Checkbox I have added a textbox and on uncheck i have tried to remove a checkbox but unable to remove a checkbox.

```
$('form input[type=checkbox]').change(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
        var className = $(this).attr('id');
        b = className + "value";
        $(this).after('&nbsp;<input type="text" id="'+b+'"  size="4" name="Value">');

    }
    else {
        var className = $(this).attr('id');
        b = className + "value";
        $("#"+b).remove();
    }
});
```

How to remove a textbox on uncheck of checkbox.

Comment: I think `$(this).attr('name')` should be `$(this).attr('id')` since you have same name for all checkbox.

Comment: sorry doesont work

Comment: EthinicalGroup[1] where 1,2,3 is value of i, id="abc" is working fine but id="'+b+'" is not working for removing text box

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if anything I can help with

Comment: your answer donot help..............while using dynamic name remove() function is not working

Comment: Could you post example of html that you generate with this foreach loop?

Comment: <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="EthinicalGroups">EthinicalGroups</label><br>
                                    <input name="EthinicalGroup" value="5e79f692ded4051398aa0911" type="checkbox" id="EthinicalGroup[0]">&nbsp;                    <label>Noodels</label><br>
                    <input name="EthinicalGroup" value="5e805df68659f13378f42427" type="checkbox" id="EthinicalGroup[1]"> <label> abc</label><br>
                
            </div>

Comment: it seems value is unique here so use `$(this).attr('value')`, it should solve your problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211133/discussion-between-selim-yildiz-and-rupak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `value` attribute of checkbox to select textboxes since `name` is the same for all checkboxes:

```
$('form input[type=checkbox]').change(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
        var className = $(this).attr('value');
        b = className + "value";
        $(this).after('&nbsp;<input type="text" id="'+b+'"  size="4" name="Value">');

    }
    else {
        var className = $(this).attr('value');
        b = className + "value";
        $("#"+b).remove();
    }
});
```